# python how to loop a function with wait without pausing the whole program

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, loops, sleep

Many people here tell you to use threading but how do you have the rest of the program running while that thread sleeps, and reruns, and sleeps again.. etc. 
I have tried normal threading with things like a while loop but that didn't work for me

edit: so the question is: how do you sleep a thread without pausing the whole program in python, if possible could you give me a example of how to do it?

edit 2: and if possible without tkinter

edit 3: fixed it, it already worked but i didn't see it because printing doesn't work across threads... Silly me.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: see title, how do you run a thread without stopping the whole program

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Currently, it's not possible to answer your question properly. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, it's probably your attempt at using threading and a `while` loop.

Comment: For edit2: what does tkinter have to do with threading?

Comment: i have stated myself that i had tried a while loop...

Comment: the time module has a [sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) method. There really should be one in the threading module, even if it just calls time.sleep().

Comment: .... I posted a link for a reason. Please read it.

Comment: rogan, there are some awnser around here which use tkinter but i dont really wanna use too many libs.

Comment: No answer requiring threading will use tkinter unless their question was about threading in a tkinter application. They are entirely different things.

Comment: james k polk could you give a example? i have tried that but i am not that good in python. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, threading works but printing doesn't work across threads. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must look for asyncio library in python, which has capabilities for pausing and resuming your function and make your function as state machine. For your sleep requirement, there's asyncio.sleep function available. Refer to http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/81223/asyncio.sleep to see examples of asyncio.sleep.

Also refer to good article at https://hackernoon.com/asyncio-for-the-working-python-developer-5c468e6e2e8e#.frn3lo7vb

Comment: thanks for awnsering, is it true that asyncio is just for python 3 or is there a 2.7 version?

Comment: It's available only in python 3.

Comment: awh, are there other good alternatives or should i just port over my program to python 3?

Comment: may be you can look for gevents, still I am not sure about it. But it also does same type of async processing similar to asyncio and it's available in python 2 also.